# Connector identification - Xbox series X

Tags: identification, connector, repair, research

I am trying to repair an Xbox Series X after a liquid damage and I found a short in the B2B connector. I need to replace it but after lots a research, I can't find the reference online.

Here it the reference from the schematics: M1094507-001. I am not sure if the schematics version is the good one so this reference might not correspond to the pictures. This connector has 80 pins in 1 row and is SMD soldered.

Here are pictures from both connector and ribbon cable:
[image: Board to board connector 80 pins - Front]

[image: Board to board connector 80 pins - Back]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Edit 1 :
Thank you very much all for your help. Here are some additional details to help us find this connector. If we have trouble finding it, it should also be the case for other people.

This ribbon cable is the same at both ends as you can see on the following pictures. The pitch it 0.5mm, thank you @Lundin. To me the number of position is 80 since the ribbon cable has only 1 side.

I looked for 1X80RCPT_40MHZ reference but nothing for the moment. I am going to search in Semtech catalog and I will keep you informed.
Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The [schematic](https://gamekonzol.hu/images/schematics/series_x_pt1.pdf) calls the connector "1X80RCPT_40MHZ" in the attributes. The M1094507-001 number is certainly Microsoft internal as all parts have the same style of number.

Comment: [Samtec](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/high-speed-board-to-board) has lots of very similar connectors. It would be helpful if you could measure center-to-center distance between the two outmost pins using a caliper, then divide by 80 to get the _pitch_ of the connector. It kind of looks like 0.5mm but I can't really tell.

Comment: @Lundin / It's divide by ***79***, not 80. There are 80 circuits on one side, which means 79 gaps between the circuits.

Comment: To help you in your search, it may help you to know the connector type.  That is an [LVDS connector](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/ffc-fpc-ribbon-connectors/lcedi-connectors.html?tab=pgp-story), not a "board-to-board" connector. They usually max out at 40 circuits. 160 circuits is quite a lot.

Comment: That cable has 2 ends. But you only show one board connector. Which end of that cable goes in the board connector you show?

Comment: @DavideAndrea Ah yeah of course.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I'm pretty sure the cable has the same connector on both ends. [Part 2](https://gamekonzol.hu/images/schematics/series_x_pt2.pdf) of the schematic has the same 80 pin board connector.

Answer (score 3):

I continue searching for this connector and I think I finnaly found it.

It is an FPC socket from Molex, part number 5017868090.

Digikey part number: [WM20781TR](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/5017868090/2818882?s=N4IgTCBcDaIOoFkwAYDsAOAjAFQEogF0BfIA)

[image]

Thank you all for your help.